# как прервать выполнение команды в linux bash?

Tags: bash

сразу скажу: команды timeout нету и нет возможности её установить =(

например запускаю top или иную другую, которая непрерывно выводит данные , и хочу чтобы через секунду или тут же по получению данных без участия ctrl+c или ctrl+z или иных действий с клавиатуры команда делал одиночный вывод и прекращала свою работу

Comment: вместо top можно использовать ps или запустить top  в batch режиме (`top -b` или `top -n 1`).

Comment: top я для примера привел... увы, у меня есть команда, которая выводит одну строку непрерывно, никаких иных параметров нету ... =( прервать её можно только по ctrl+c и все. а надо запустить программу и через секунду выйти обратно в шелл =(

Comment: `man timeout`: `sudo apt-get install timeout; timeout 10 ping google.com` Ну и свои велосипеды: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068

Answer (score 2):

Если что, всегда можно попробовать скопировать timeout с подходящей системы или написать свой на баше/перле. На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay) есть ряд примеров. Вот самый маленький

```
#!/bin/sh
( your_command ) & pid=$!
( sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
wait $pid 2>/dev/null && pkill -HUP -P $watcher
```

Если имя программы точно известно, то можно даже так

```
(sleep 3 && killall program) & ./program
```

Comment: @vilfred Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа), если он решил ваш вопрос.